# Selenium: how to find div with specific content?

Tags: html, xpath, selenium

I need to find a `<div>` with certain content and `click` it from Selenium, as so:

```
<tr>
  <td>clickAndWait</td>
  <td>//div[@class='gwt-Label' ***WITH CONTENT='Logout'***]</td>
  <td>5000</td>
</tr>
```

Is there some way to do this? I don't want to use an absolute xpath.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
 //div[@class='gwt-Label' and contains(., 'Logout')]
```

Comment: Sounds great, but I can't get it to work. Searched for documentation, but found none; do you have a link?

Comment: Oh. You need to drop the single quotes around '.'. Edited

Comment: Ah, it's XPath, hadn't realized that. Still doesn't work, but hopefully I'll be able to fix it now. Thanks!

Comment: Selenium identifies the locator, finds the div, but the click never comes through! Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the div is the appropriate target of the click ? The way I remember GWT there's an awful lot of layers

Answer (score 8):

You could also use CSS locators:

```
<div class="gwt-Label">This FindMe DIV</div>
```

Could be located using:

```
css=.gwt-Label:contains('FindMe')
```

Comment: Selenium identifies the locator, finds the div, but the click never comes through! Any ideas?

Comment: It might be that the DIV isn't the element that responds to the click. Is there a parent/child element that could be more suitable? There are also sometimes issues with `click` and you could try the `mouseDown`, `mouseUp` commands instead.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your XPath just isn't quite doing what you think. You may need to use the string() function to concatenate all the text in a block.

For example, in TestPlan (using Selenium as backend) you would do something like this:

```
Click //div[@class='gwt-Label'][contains(string(),'Logout')]
```

Note the use of string()